# Form to display checkbox with title without the ability to edit title

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been playing around with Django forms and it's a bit of a headache. I came to a point where I can display my form properly but I only want to edit part of it's data, not all of them.

Specifically: I have a Product model that has a title and a featured bool field. I want a form that displays all the products names with a tickbox next to it. The user is able to edit the featured property of each Product on the same form, but only that! My problem is that with the current setup, the displayed title is also an input field, not a simple text. If I change the template to display {{ productForm.title.value }} instead of {{ productForm.title }} it displays it as a text but the form failes the validation (It requires the title to have a value, since it cannot be null).

Model is plain simple, title and featured fields with CharField and BooleanField types. Validation branch is also not taken care of in the sample but "is_valid()" returns false.

views.py

```
def featured_product(request):
FeaturedProductFormSet = modelformset_factory(Product, fields=('title', 'featured'))
if request.method == "POST":
    productForms = FeaturedProductFormSet(request.POST)
    if productForms.is_valid():
        productForms.save()
        return redirect('/admin/')
else:
    productForms = FeaturedProductFormSet()

return render_to_response(
    'vetco_app/featured_products.html',
    {
        'productForms': productForms,
    },
    context_instance=RequestContext(request)
)
```

featured_products.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            Termék neve
        </th>
        <th>
            Kiemelt
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for productForm in productForms %}
        {% if not forloop.last %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ productForm.id }}
                    {{ productForm.title }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ productForm.featured }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>
    {{ productForms.management_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="Save">Save</button>
</p>
```

How to make it display only the text of the title without the need to validate it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply provide context:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
context = RequestContext(request, {"your_model":your_model")
```

now in templates just write:

```
 {{ your_model.some_attribute }}
```